# Using listactivity view to create table in android

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to android. I want to create a table in my Wapplication that will have three columns. Once column would have string, another would have a image and last column would have a integer. Again, I want to have table rows selectable. Can this be achieved by extending ListActivity ?  What is the best to way to create such a table in android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a chance to go through the official [NotePad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html)?  I am new to Android as well, and I would highly recommend it.  It walks you through all the basics of creating a ListActivity with well documented code.  To create your "table" you would change the layout (row_view.xml), created in Step 5 of Exercise 1, from a TextView to a RelativeLayout.  Inside this RelativeLayout you would have a TextView for the string, an ImageView for the image, and another TextView for the integer.  Hope that helps you get started.

Comment: I believe the official Android parlance for this is "Compound Control": http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you probably want a ListView that contains rows with a custom layout.  There's an example here: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/